# Generic case UDP packet loss?

Tags: networking, udp

I'm designing a networking protocol for a game, with acked events and non-acked real-time data. Just for design considerations, what kind of packet losses can I expect, when I keep my packet sizes less than 512 bytes, and the total throughput less than 128Kbps?

I'm looking for realistic numbers on the % of packet loss, and the average chunk of packets getting lost (just one, or often 4 in a row?).

Comment: no way to tell. udp is a "best effort" protocol. a router may decide it hates your guts and dump all of your packets, or it'll play nice and get all of them through. and this can happen on every single router between the server and the client.

Comment: This would depend a lot on the network, traffic, congestion, links in between, etc. Coming up with a general `%loss` won't really be possible.

Comment: I'm looking for some realistic numbers for a general household without anyone downloading or some similar stress, because I really have no idea what kind of numbers I can expect, can this be as high as 30% in a normal use case, or am I more looking into 1-2%? The reason I want to know this is that due to bandwidth restrictions I can not synchronize and acknowledge all data for a game (a projectile shooter), so I have to make tradeoffs. Packet loss is a large factor in this, so I'd like to have some clue.

Comment: @icepack: I'd be interested in both.

Comment: There is no generic answer to this generic question. It depends entirely on environmental factors that cannot be quantified in the abstract. You are going to have to test and measure. Not a real question, and also off topic.

Comment: @Jean Rolled back your edit. Not 'more appealing' at all, just illegible. Please desist.